# BoxPlot failure

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am having trouble with creating a boxplot. There are no errors, it just doesn't show all the point:
[image: 3 df's :]

Till 513

My code:

```
data = [df2['Counts'][0:470], df2['Counts'][471:494],df2['Counts'][495:]]
fig1, ax4 = plt.subplots()
ax4.set_title('Furter vs Krum serum')
plt.xticks([] ,['F4','Km','Liquid' ])
ax4.boxplot(data)
plt.show()
```

The box plot is missing the "Km and liquid" parts (there is only one point) and shows only the F4 which is the largest set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your dataframe doesn't contain the information you're expecting. Or maybe the `F4` part has a completely different range? If e.g. the values of `Km`, `Liquid` are 10 times smaller, they would get reduced to just a line near zero.

You could print out `df2['Counts'][471:494]` and `df2['Counts'][495:]` to see how the values look like.  The code below adds a scatter plot to see all the points.

Some remarks:

- [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) as in `array[a:b]` goes from `a` till `b-1` (similar to python's range function). So you might want to use `data = [df2['Counts'][0:471], df2['Counts'][471:495],df2['Counts'][495:]]` or so.
- It is recommended not to mix the `ax.` and `plt.` way of [calling matplotlib functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html).
- Usually it is better to call the `xticks` functions after creating the main plot, as many functions try to set their own ticks.
- When setting the `xticklabels`, it is recommended to set the corresponding `xticks` at the same time. In this case, the ticks are numbered internally as `1, 2, 3`.

Here is some example code showing how things could fit together. To help debugging, a scatter plot is added to see where all the points really are.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Counts': np.random.normal(0.02, 0.002, 513)})

data = [df2['Counts'][0:471], df2['Counts'][471:495], df2['Counts'][495:]]
fig1, ax4 = plt.subplots()
ax4.boxplot(data)
for i in range(3):
    ax4.scatter(np.repeat([i+1], len(data[i])), data[i])
ax4.set_title('Furter vs Krum serum')
ax4.set_xticks([1, 2, 3])
ax4.set_xticklabels(['F4', 'Km', 'Liquid'])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]